# Admin dashboard for React blogging site

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

[image]

I am trying to build a kind of blogging site using MERN technology, where I am working on a restful api with node, express and mongodb... I have three sections or categories on frontend (React) Quotes, Stories, and News.

I have created schema and routes for all of them in different files. Schemas are not same.

Now I am confuse about admin form (dashboard) from where I will send data to api? Do I have to create a separate form for each section?

How can I make a dynamic admin form that accepts any kind of schemas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [keystoneJS](https://keystonejs.com/) to build an out-of-the-box admin. You can connect your mongoose schemas to it and it does the magic for you.